# Making columns optional in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a bit of an Oracle dilemma.

I have a table consisting of 5 columns: one PK, two FKs, one INT value and one Date.
I also have a sequence set up for my PK.
I set up a trigger that replaces the PK by an auto-incremented value and the Date by the current date so that you can enter the values (null, FK, FK, INT, null) but I was wondering if there was a way to modify my trigger so that I can enter simply (FK, FK, INT)? As it stands (obviously) if I enter only 3 values I get the ORA-00947: not enough values error.

```
CREATE or REPLACE trigger TRIG_new_product
    before insert on product
    for each row
    BEGIN
        SELECT sq_product.nextval, sysdate
            into :new.productID, :new.productDate
            FROM dual;
    END TRIG_new_product;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to supply values for a column, don't list it in the insert statement:

```
insert into product 
   (fk_column, fk_column, int_column)
values
   (42, 24, 4224);
```

The error message "not enough" values has nothing to do with your trigger and probably stems from the fact that you didn't specify the columns in your insert statement. In that case you *have* to supply a value for each column. You probably did something like this:

```
insert into product  -- no columns specified therefore all are required
values 
  (42, 24, 4224);
```

Of course leaving out columns during insert will only work if they are defined as nullable.

---

Btw: your trigger could be written a bit simpler:

```
CREATE or REPLACE trigger TRIG_new_product
    before insert on product
    for each row
    BEGIN
        :new.productID := sq_product.nextval;
        :new.productDate := sysdate;
    END TRIG_new_product;
```

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: which is the lowest supported version of Oracle as of now.

Comment: yes, but there are plenty of 10g, 9i and 8i databases out there being supported, so just wanted it noted, that's all.